# Unable to query all Json Values in Maria Db JSON data using SQL query Where A certain Condition Is Met

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, mariadb

I'm unable to select all values inside a JSON column in Maria Db which meets a certain condition. The data in the database field is organized as multiple items posted in a JSON array.

How can I retrieve for example *all gson values* where  *receivedStatus* is *YES*?

Below is my Sample Data

```json
[{"itemCode":"LAB-BLOOD-TRAN-0001","serviceName":"Blood Crosmatching","qty":"1","rate":"1500.0","total":"1500.0","classification":"","department":"LABORATORY","inputDate":"2023-02-09","paymentStatus":"NO","receivedStatus":"YES","processed":"","cmTotal":"0.0","receivingUsername":"","processingUsername":"","approvalStatus":"","specimen":"","doctorsRequestingName":""},

{"itemCode":"LAB-BIOCHEM-0001","serviceName":"ALBUMIN","qty":"1","rate":"500.0","total":"500.0","classification":"","department":"LABORATORY","inputDate":"2023-02-09","paymentStatus":"NO","receivedStatus":"NO","processed":"","cmTotal":"0.0","receivingUsername":"","processingUsername":"","approvalStatus":"","specimen":"","doctorsRequestingName":""},
{"itemCode":"LAB-IMMUN-001","serviceName":"17 Beta Estradiol ","qty":"1.0","rate":"4500.0","total":"4500.0","classification":"IMMUNOLOGY","department":"LABORATORY","inputDate":"2023-02-09 17:01:27","paymentStatus":"YES","receivedStatus":"","processed":"","cmTotal":"4500.0","receivingUsername":"","processingUsername":"","approvalStatus":"APPROVED","specimen":"Urea","doctorsRequestingName":""},

{"itemCode":"LAB-IMMUN-004","serviceName":"Acetyl Receptor Antibodies ","qty":"1","rate":"12500.0","total":"12500.0","classification":"","department":"LABORATORY","inputDate":"2023-02-09","paymentStatus":"NO","receivedStatus":"NO","processed":"","cmTotal":"0.0","receivingUsername":"","processingUsername":"","approvalStatus":"","specimen":"","doctorsRequestingName":""}]
```

I tried:

select * from (

```
SELECT distinct patient_name,age,visit_no,sex,laboratory_requests,JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(t.laboratory_requests, CONCAT('$[', x.seq, '].department'))) AS department,
  JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(t.laboratory_requests, CONCAT('$[', x.seq, '].receivedStatus'))) AS receivedStatus
  FROM  pb_doctors_requests t
  INNER JOIN ( 
    SELECT seq FROM seq_0_to_10
  ) AS x ON JSON_EXTRACT(t.laboratory_requests, CONCAT('$[', x.seq, ']')) IS NOT NULL
) as s
where receivedStatus in ('NO');
```

Screenshot of what I was trying:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzIAa.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the values of a specific element by key number :

```
select json_extract(laboratory_requests, '$[0].receivedStatus')
from pb_doctors_requests;
```

If you want to remove Quotes use `JSON_UNQUOTE`:

```
select JSON_UNQUOTE(json_extract(laboratory_requests, '$[0].receivedStatus'))
from pb_doctors_requests;
```

To get values of all the array elements you can use `JSON_TABLE` :

```
SELECT get_values.* 
FROM pb_doctors_requests, 
     JSON_TABLE(laboratory_requests, '$[*]' COLUMNS (
         department VARCHAR(40)  PATH '$.department',
         receivedStatus VARCHAR(40)  PATH '$.receivedStatus'
      )
) get_values;
```

This is working version for mariadb 10.3 :

```
SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(t.laboratory_requests, CONCAT('$[', x.seq, '].department'))) AS department,
  JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(t.laboratory_requests, CONCAT('$[', x.seq, '].receivedStatus'))) AS receivedStatus,
  JSON_LENGTH(t.laboratory_requests)
FROM  pb_doctors_requests t
INNER JOIN ( 
    SELECT seq FROM seq_0_to_10
) AS x ON JSON_EXTRACT(t.laboratory_requests, CONCAT('$[', x.seq, ']')) IS NOT NULL
```

[Demo for mysql 8/ mariadb 10.6 and higher](https://dbfiddle.uk/hg5Sa061)

[Demo for mariadb 10.3](https://dbfiddle.uk/wrgpO_8X)

Comment: Thank You For Answering My Question ,Can you Kindly select all items in Json column that received status is no or received status= yes . Like the one you have shared for  using 'get_values.*' function. Im Using Maria Db but im unable to use get_values.* functions in my scenario

Comment: which mariadb version ? get_values is just an alias not a function

Comment: Maria Version '10.3.37-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.20.04.1' And i tried pasting your third query its displaying  this error        SELECT *  FROM pb_doctors_requests,       JSON_TABLE(laboratory_requests, '$[*]' COLUMNS (          department VARCHAR(40)  PATH '$.department',          receivedStatus VARCHAR(40)  PATH '$.receivedStatus'       ) ) Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(laboratory_requests, '$[*]' COLUMNS (          department VARCHAR(40)  PATH ...' at line 3 0.000 sec

Comment: I have used your code and im so happy it has worked and now able to sort some values . Be blessed . However my main interest was to return all **Json Values** eg _itemCode,_ _ServiceName_ _and_ _all __other_ _colums_ in the form of Json Array Still but now with limited data eg with already removed *Json Items* which does not meet the conditions. eg the select that returns json values that have not been received or those that have been received . May be i didnt explain it further why i needed to test the condition

Comment: If you see it answer your question can you approve it ?